# Closing a node HTTP server gracefully - server.close callback not firing

Tags: node.js, http

I have a node.js (v20.4.0) server implemented atop the built-in [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserver). Upon receipt of `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`, I would like for the server to stop accepting new connections, finish any in-flight requests, and then exit once all in-flight requests are complete.

Here's a simplified version of how my server is set up (`server.js`):

```
const http = require("http");

const requestListener = (_, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("howdy!");
};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
const host = 'localhost'
const port = 8888

const shutdown = () => {
  console.log(`Got SIGINT, calling server.close() ...`);
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Server closed, exiting')
    process.exit(0)
  })
}

process.on("SIGINT", shutdown)

server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

If I run this in a terminal, and then press ctrl-c to send a `SIGINT`, it works as expected. However, the following sequence of events will cause the callback to `close` to never be invoked:

1. Start the server (`node server.js`)
2. Open `http://localhost:8888` in a Chrome tab
3. Press ctrl-c on the terminal window where the server was started

I see the 'Got SIGINT' message, but the callback passed to `server.close` never fires (at least not until I quit Chrome).

The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#serverclosecallback) for `server.close()` says:

> Stops the server from accepting new connections and closes all connections connected to this server which are not sending a request or waiting for a response.

What is Chrome doing that's making node think that there is still a connection open which is "sending a request or waiting for a response"?

*Edit*

Confirmed via Chrome dev tools that Chrome is sending a `Connection: keep-alive` header with the request, and that the node server is responding with the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2023 21:08:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

*Edit 2*

It looks to me like I'm hitting the issue described in https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41578. The `server.closeIdleConnections` method (added in node 18.2.0 via https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/42812) was intended to address this problem, but does not appear to actually work in my case. I'm trying to get to a repro case that doesn't involve Chrome itself.

Comment: Try this: `server.close((err) => { if (err) console.log(err); // ...`. Does it show something?

Comment: Also, this behavior could happen if `Connection:keep-alive` header is present (but it should be disabled by default, so maybe it's not your case)

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi it does not - the issue is that close callback is never invoked at all.

Answer (score 0):

When the client sends a (to tell the server it supports to keep alive connections)

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

header and the server responds with

```
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5s
```

the connection isn't closed until this timeout elapsed. And `server.close()` will wait for those open connections to be closed. So if you

1. start your server
2. send a *single* request to http://localhost:8888 from your chrome
3. immediately send a SIGINT to your server process

the server process will wait for this one open connection to close and then terminate the server (ie it will take about 5 seconds, before the callback of `server.close` is executed)

But if you

1. start your server
2. send a *single* request to http://localhost:8888 from your chrome
3. wait 10 seconds without sending another request from the browser
4. send a SIGINT to your server process

the server won't have any open connections anymore (because the keep-alive timeout already elapsed) and will terminate the server immediately (and of course also execute the callback of `server.close()`)

One problem seems to be: The docs just say:

> Stops the server from accepting new connections [...]

But as long as the existing connection is still open (ie the keep-alive timeout did not elapse yet), even if `server.close()` was already called, the server keeps accepting requests via that open connection. Why, because the server only stops accepting new connections, but not accepting new requests on an open connection. And if you have something periodically querying your server via such an open connection, it will never get closed.

You can try this as follows

1. start your server
2. send a request to http://localhost:8888
3. send SIGINT to your server
4. quickly refresh your page in chrome
5. keep pressing f5 to refresh your page

The server won't terminate. Only after you stop refreshing your page, it will terminate after 5 seconds.

A way around this unwanted behaviour could be the following

```
let shouldCloseConnection = false;
const requestListener = (_, res) => {
    if (shouldCloseConnection) {
        res.setHeader('Connection', 'close')
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("howdy!");
};

...

const shutdown = () => {
  console.log(`Got SIGINT, calling server.close() ...`);
  shouldCloseConnection = true;
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Server closed, exiting')
  })
}
```

Ie, once the server received the SIGINT signal, it stops sending a `Connection: keep-alive` but sends `Connection: close` instead. Which will cause the connection to be closed after the current request has finished. So all open connections will either be closed after the timeout or after the next request, whichever happens first.

This way, you shouldn't even need the `process.exit(0)` in the callback. Unless of course, you have other open timers/promises/connections ... still waiting for completion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't think that keep-alive behavior fully explains what's going on here, though. Examining packet dumps shows that the connection winds up hanging around for much longer than the 5s keep-alive timeout, even without any keep-alive frames being sent by the browser.

Comment: I can only tell you what my tests with your minimal example showed. The server stayed alive as long as the client sent request. Once the client stopped sending requests, the server stopped gracefully. If it doesn't on your side, there is something else in your code